# Differences between [joint-distribution] and [bivariate]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, tag-excerpt

I wonder if [joint-distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/joint-distribution) and [bivariate](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bivariate), have been used interchangeably on Cross Validated?

- [joint-distribution] was used in 255 questions; it has an excerpt and a simple wiki.
- [bivariate] was used in 126 questions; it has a simple excerpt and no wiki.

Can they be considered synonyms? If not, would it be interesting to update the tag excerpts to emphasize what is (are) the difference(s) between them?

Comment: At a minimum, *joint-distribution* strikes me as broader than *bivariate*, in that JD can apply to >2 variables.

Comment: I don't think they're interchangeable. Bivariate is a subset of joint (that adds specific, useful information)

Comment: When people start in statistics, they commonly work in R. But then they move on to $R^2$, and finally to $R^n$. Does that sound right?

Comment: @GeoMatt22 Snuck that pun past the censors, didn't ya?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [bivariate](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bivariate) tag is a [proper subset](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProperSubset.html) of [joint-distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/joint-distribution).

I have updated wiki excerpts as follows:

> Joint probability distribution of several random variables gives the probability that all of them simultaneously lie in a particular region.

and

> Joint probability distribution of two variables.

Briefly looking at the questions, it seems that most questions in the `[joint-distribution]` are actually about bivariate distributions, even though many of them are not tagged with `[bivariate]`. Given that, we could consider mapping [bivariate](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bivariate)$\to$[joint-distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/joint-distribution). I do not have strong feelings about this. What do people think?

Comment: I want to accept your answer, the excerpts were clarified. I hope questions will be tagged more properly from now on. The synonym suggestion, which I agree, seems to not have received enough support. If this post collects more upvotes with time, we can think of (re)bringing this issue. What do you think?

Comment: Agreed, @AndreSilva.